# PHP script dispaying wrong time

Tags: php

My PHP script is displaying the wrong time. For eg. the time on my system is 3:10 PM while the script shows 9:40 AM.

I am working on Windows XP. The server package is that of "yPortable WebServer". Checking some other questions on this site I even made the following change => date.timezone = "Asia/Calcutta", in the php.ini.dist and php.ini files. But still no change.

Comment: have you restarted apache after modifying the `php.ini` file?

Comment: Or you can do it in your code : <?php define('TIMEZONE', 'Asia/Calcutta');  


    date_default_timezone_set(TIMEZONE); ?>

Comment: don't change the php.ini timeZone if you are making international site

Comment: "Carlos" Yes I restarted the web server and after making the changes. And, by the way, it is not Apache but LightTPD web server.

Comment: "somebody in trouble": Nope it is for personal use only.

Comment: Do you live in Calcutta? and is the server with you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a good idea to always [set default timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in your script when using date functions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried echo-ing date('e') or date('r') to see if you have set the timezone settings correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the timezone in the code worked just fine. Thank You!

OK! This seems silly. I just restarted the OS itself, and it seems to work without setting the timezone in the code. Some glitch somewhere, maybe because the system was on continuously for too long(couple of days).